# Using python CDLL to load dll, but no function from c code show up

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes, cl

I'm trying to import function written in c code into python. A minimal example I have tried is

```c
//test.h
__declspec(dllexport)  int HW(int, int);
```

```c
//test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test.h"

__declspec(dllexport) int HW(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

I also tried to remove the `__declspec(dllexport)` in either files. Then I did the following in Visual Studio 2019 CMD

```
cl /LD test.c
```

or

```
cl /LD test.c \libs\python37.lib
```

In python I did

```py
from ctypes import *
a = CDLL('test.dll')
```

It turns out that HW is not an attribute of a. Which part did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to load a 32-bit DLL into 64-bit Python, or vice versa?

Comment: Does specifying the full path to `test.dll` help?

Comment: I guess I made a mistake trying to see the attribute. It is within the ```_FuncPtr``` attribute. I wasn't able to see it but I'm able to call it. Thanks @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Is the `__declspec(dllexport)` necessary? I don't wanna modify my collague's code in case otehr people are using it as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum code you need is the following.  `test.h` isn't needed to export the function, and neither of the other includes were used.

```
__declspec(dllexport) int HW(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Compile with `cl /LD test.c` (Microsoft).  The python library isn't required.  Make sure to use the 32-bit compiler if using 32-bit Python, or 64-bit compiler if using 64-bit Python.

Demo of use:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> a = CDLL('./test')
>>> a.HW
<_FuncPtr object at 0x000001E44AB7BA00>
>>> a.HW(1,2)
3
```

Note you won't see the functions by inspection (i.e., `dir(a)`) until you access the function once:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> a = CDLL('./test')
>>> dir(a)
['_FuncPtr', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_func_flags_', '_func_restype_', '_handle', '_name']
>>> a.HW
<_FuncPtr object at 0x0000020A92B7B930>
>>> dir(a)
['HW', '_FuncPtr', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_func_flags_', '_func_restype_', '_handle', '_name']
```